# Game restart Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a restart button on the Game Over Menu, I have a fadein for the game over screen when it touches and obstacle.

Every time you hit retry it hides it, problem is that it is still touching it, so how could i reset the whole game so he is not touching it? Below is some code that I have tryed but did not work because the player is still frozen.

```
 $('#levelOne').animate({
      'margin-top': '-=1520px'
  });
```

And here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/86/

Comment: It looks like you'd need to reset both the`#levelOne` back to a margin-top of 0, and reset the player back to it's original position.

Comment: the game has a bug where the object I control goes off screen.

Comment: It diddnt work, thanks though, anyother ideas? I was thinking a load level function and calling it again but it did not work :/

Answer (score 1):

As @cjspurg said you must reset the `margin-top` of `#levelOne`
But you also need to reset the `margin-left` of `#player` and lastly start animating `#levelOne` again.

I updated your `$("#retry").click` function as follows:

```
$('#retry').click(function () {
    $('#GameOver').fadeOut();

    // NEW LOGIC
    $("#levelOne").css('margin-top', '-1520px');
    $("#player").css('border', 'solid 1px green');
    $("#player").css('margin-left', '223px');

    $('#levelOne').animate({
       'margin-top': '+=1520px'
    }, speed);

});
```

Please consider putting some / all of that logic into functions as you feel appropriate.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ld7usqn/) of the working game.